# Can the Books app be automated or scripted?

Tags: applescript, catalina

I don't know much about AppleScript or Automator. I use Catalina, up to date as of today, 2020 Jan 06.
Today I was trying to use Automator to change the Category of multiple books in my Books Library, which inexplicably Apple does not support.  There are no actions that seem to take a selection and operate on the items in the selection in Books.  I looked at AppleScript and there does not appear to be a Books dictionary.
Can the Books app be automated or scripted?  Or am I out of luck?
If so, how?
Thanks!

Comment: No. Yes. ­­­­­­­

Comment: I'm not on Catalina, but can you use UI scripting? That's generally the way to script apps without dictionaries. It's a bit painful though.

Comment: I'm not familiar with UI scripting method on OSX.  Is this a third party solution?  I looked in Automator and tried to use the Record feature and it ignored everything except bringing Books to the foreground.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there are no dictionaries, the answer seems to be no, you can't Apple Script them. You can always try to use UI scripting (simulate user clicks) but the functionality must be available inside the app. Which is not the case here. Anyway the category seems to have been abandoned in last versions.